# Unable to run Eclipse RCP 32 bit application in 64 bit eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, 64-bit, eclipse-rcp

Previously I created a RCP applicatino using Eclipse 32 bit luna. Later I have installed 64 bit jdk and 64 bit Eclipse Luna.

When I am trying to run the previous application using jdk 64 bit and Eclipse 64 bit, There is no compilation error, but while running the project as Eclipse Application, it gives the following error (com.app.editor.Application is the entry class for my RCP application)-

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.app.Editor was unable to load class com.app.editor.Application.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.editor.Application cannot be found by com.app.Editor_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    ... 16 more
```

Can please anyone help me?

Thanks in Advance!

Note: project name is com.app.editor
Here is the folder structure -
[image]

Here is the MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Editor
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.app.Editor;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.app.editor.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: APP
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 com.ibm.icu,
 org.eclipse.jface.databinding,
 org.eclipse.core.databinding.property,
 org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable,
 org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans,
 org.eclipse.core.databinding,
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.9.1"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: /Lib/mariadb-java-client-1.2.3.jar .
Export-Package: com.app.editor;
  uses:="org.osgi.framework,
   org.eclipse.ui,
   org.eclipse.jface.action,
   org.eclipse.equinox.app,
   org.eclipse.jface.resource,
   org.eclipse.ui.application,
   org.eclipse.ui.plugin",
 com.app.editor.actions;uses:="org.eclipse.jface.action",
 com.app.editor.beans,
 com.app.editor.functionalities;
  uses:="org.eclipse.swt.graphics,
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets,
   org.eclipse.jface.dialogs,
   javax.swing.tree",
 com.app.editor.handlers;uses:="org.eclipse.core.commands",
 com.app.editor.perspectives;uses:="org.eclipse.ui",
 com.app.editor.views;
  uses:="com.app.editor.beans,
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets,
   org.eclipse.swt.custom,
   com.app.editor.functionalities,
   org.eclipse.core.databinding,
   org.eclipse.jface.viewers,
   org.eclipse.ui.part"
```

Also, the build.properties looks like this -

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               Application.e4xmi,\
               icons/,\
               plugin_customization.ini
```

Plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="com.app.editor.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            name="RCP Perspective"
            class="com.app.editor.perspectives.Perspective"
            id="com.app.Editor.perspective">
      </perspective>
      <perspective
            class="com.app.editor.perspectives.NewFilePerspective"
            id="com.app.Editor.newFileperspective"
            name="New File Prespective">
      </perspective>
      <perspective
            class="com.app.editor.perspectives.OpenFilePerspective"
            id="com.app.Editor.openFileperspective"
            name="Open File Perspective">
      </perspective>
      <perspective
            class="com.app.editor.perspectives.CloseViewPerspective"
            id="com.app.Editor.closeViewperspective"
            name="Close View Prespective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.NewFileHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.New"
            name="New">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.OpenHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.Open"
            name="Open">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.ExitHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.commands.Exit"
            name="Exit">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.CloseHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.close"
            name="Close">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.AboutHandler"
            description="About"
            id="com.app.Editor.about"
            name="About">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.SaveHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.Save"
            name="Save">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.SaveAsHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.SaveAs"
            name="Save As..">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="fileMenu"
               label="File">
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.New"
                  label="New"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.Open"
                  label="Open"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.Save"
                  label="Save"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.SaveAs"
                  label="Save As.."
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.close"
                  label="Close"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.commands.Exit"
                  label="Exit"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
         <menu
               id="helpMenu"
               label="Help">
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.about"
                  label="About"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view
            class="com.app.editor.views.OpenView"
            id="com.app.Editor.openView"
            name="OpenView"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
      <view
            class="com.app.editor.views.CloseView"
            id="com.app.Editor.closeView"
            name="CloseView"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
      <view
            allowMultiple="false"
            class="com.app.editor.views.NewView"
            id="com.app.Editor.newView"
            name="NewView"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
      <view
            class="com.app.editor.views.TreeView"
            id="com.app.Editor.treeView"
            name="TreeView"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Well do you have a class `com.app.editor.Application`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg. Yes, I do have the Application class. Please let me put the folder structure here-

Comment: Provided the screenshot for folder structure and the MANIFEST.MF file.

Comment: Is this the full stack trace? Are you sure that there are no more nested exceptions?